# Decrypt data Xcode to PHP

Tags: php, iphone, xcode, security, private-key

I'm making an application with Xcode which encrypts information using the private key of a certificate, this information is sent to a server using a POST in PHP (Eg: username = "encrypted data") and I want to decrypt this information in the PHP with the private key and get the real information, I encrypted the information with SecKeyEncrypt in Xcode and then sent to PHP, but how I can decrypt it with the private key in php?

Comment: That depends on what crypt algorithm is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `mcrypt_decrypt` that comes with the `mcrypt` extension.